# Find first column which satisfies a condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I will try to make it clear.

First of all, I am not responsible of the database design nor I am able to change anything about it.

My question is a bit weird and I can't find a good solution to it.

**Let's take this database example**:

```
MAKE     MODEL     CY_2015     CY_2016     CY_2017     CY_2018     CY_2019      ...  

Nissan   xxxx      0           0           0           15475       1425723      ...
Ford     xx        0           0           75542       82317       12454        ...
...
```

**And this is the output I would like to get**:

```
MAKE     MODEL     START_YEAR

Nissan   xxxx      2018
Ford     xx        2017
...
```

I don't know if you noticed how I built the output: In fact, I want to get the models and their "start year". 
Let's take the first model as example.

- Nissan xxxx has "0" everytime (CY_2015, CY_2016 and CY_2017 are "0") until "CY_2018" where it is not "0" anymore, so "2018" IS the "start year".
- Ford xx has "0" everytime (CY_2015, CY_2016 are "0") until "CY_2017" where it is not "0" anymore thus "2017" is the "start year".

Basically I have nothing to come up with as I have no idea how to perform such query (or something that could at least help me to get close to the output I want), so please excuse me for that.

Please note that the DBMS is Access, as I know that it can bring problems.

Comment: how many CY's like CY_2015, CY_2016..... are there in database table ?

Comment: In fact it goes from 2006 to 2023 @NinadAvasare

Comment: You should consider normalizing the table structure.

Comment: Well, it's *possible* to loop through the Fields container to get a list of fields (since you'll want this done dynamically rather than with a static list) and check each one for values, but in all honestly it'd be a total mess and I don't know if you could even do it in the proper order.  The only other way to do it (with an equal mess) is to write a humongous IIF statement and check each field one at a time.  Something like, "Start_Year: IIF(CY_2018 = 0, IIF(CY_2017 = 0, IIF(CY_2016 = 0, CY_2015, "0"), "2016"), "2017"), "2018")"  Or something like that.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I now the table structure is terrible but I am not allowed to change it. I can only perform whatever queries I want on it but unfortunately I can't change the database design.

Comment: @JohnnyBones the idea to make successive "IIF" can eventually work as I can dynamically build the query using VB. Don't know if there is a better solution tho

Comment: as commented above, use unpivot to normalise, get rid of all zeros by filter, rownumber over partition by make/model and ordered by the new column containg CY_xxxx-values, filter for rownumbers equal to 1. this would work in SQL Server but now i get pointed to the fact, this is Access, sorry, got no idea

Comment: I would simply write a VBA function to loop the records and columns, and write the results to an output table.

Comment: @DerU - Unpivot?  Over Partition?  Do these work in Access?  I know they do in SQL Server but I didn't think Access could do that.

Comment: @DerU Unpivot can maybe be performed on Access (at least tricked) but I'm not sure that over partition is possible

Comment: @Andre that would mean looping through all the rows one by one and performing as many queries as rows (there is about a million rows)

Comment: Not queries, just a recordset loop and a loop over its values per row. I doubt it would be slower than the nested IIF query. If the database file is on a local disk, it might be faster than you expect. -- But a million rows is a relevant piece of information. In this case I would most certainly move (or copy) the data to SQL Server and process it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is similar to Gordon's, except I prefer one `Switch` expression over multiple nested `IIf` expressions.

```sql
SELECT
    MAKE,
    MODEL,
    Switch
        (
            CY_2006 > 0, 2006,
            CY_2007 > 0, 2007,
            CY_2008 > 0, 2008,
            ... etc ...
            CY_2023 > 0, 2023,
            True, Null
        ) AS START_YEAR
```

`Switch` returns the *value* from the first *condition,value* pair where the *condition* evaluates as True, and ignores the remaining pairs.

The last *condition,value* pair (`True, Null`) means `START_YEAR` would be Null when none of the previous conditions are True.

Comment: I like this one, certainly one of the "cleanest" way to do this considering the database design I have. I'll give it a try and update it as accepted tomorrow

Comment: Fully working, I get the output I was expecting so thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with massive, nested `iif()` statements:

```
select make, model,
       iif(cy_2015 > 0, '2015',
           iif(cy_2016 > 0, '2016'
               iif(cy_2017 > 0, '2017'
                   iif(cy_2018 > 0, '2018'
                       iif(cy_2019 > 0, '2019')
                      )
                  )
              )
          ) as start_year
```

However, this would probably be much easier to do in the query that generates the data that you are working with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think would be the "better" method in terms of performance: 
1. Building dynamically the query you gave me using VB (nested IIF) and performing the query to get the result.
2. Use @Andre method that uses VB to loop through the rows of the recordset, and then throught the fields and get the output

Comment: @TheoBabilon: best to try it out. Perhaps first on a subset of one MAKE.